# wxDC::wxTextEntryDialog escapes newlines

Tags: wxwidgets

wxTextEntryDialog converts '\n' into '\\n'

This code

```
 dc.DrawText( "line a\nline b", 10, 100 );
```

outputs what I expect

```
line a
line b
```

So I code this:

```
wxTextEntryDialog dlg(this,"","Name the flower");
dlg.ShowModal();
setName( dlg.GetValue().wc_str() );
dc->DrawText( getName(), 10, 10 );
```

and type in

```
line a\nline b
```

and the display shows

line a\nline b

Using wxWidgets v3.0.1 on Windows

Answer (score 0):

The [drawing sample](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/master/samples/drawing/drawing.cpp#L871) shows that `DrawText()` does work with multiple lines, so something must be wrong with your code. I can't say what though as you don't show us much, the snippet you do show wouldn't even compile because the arguments order is wrong, so clearly you must be doing something different in your real program.

Comment: Found the problem when preparing real code for you.  wxTextEntryDialog is adding an escape when I type in the text, changing la\nlb to la\\nlb

Comment: Huh? `wxTextEntryDialog` doesn't do anything like this. OTOH you don't really expect entering the two characters, backslash and 'n', into the text control to result in a new line, do you?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to add

```
wxString name = getName();
name.Replace("\\n","\n");
dc->DrawText( name, 10, 10 );
```

[image]

Full source code for demo app at https://www.dropbox.com/s/l6wu7pxtwvcj9vp/so26003871.zip?dl=0

Comment: The workaround is certainly necessary.  See screenshot and source code posted.

Comment: There is a huge misunderstanding here. This is not a workaround because there is nothing to work around. Entering backslash and 'n' into a dialog doesn't somehow magically create a new line.

Comment: @VZ Please try the code: " dc2.DrawText( "line a\nline b", 10, 100 );" and notice how the new line magically appears.

Comment: Yes, and why is this a surprise, exactly? You seriously need to revisit the chapter about the escape sequences in your favourite C or C++ book.

Comment: It is not a surprise, this is what I expect.  As I wrote in my question.  What surprises me is that the wxTextEntryDialog adds a second escape, changing '\n' into '\\n' which causes the problem described in my question.  May I ask if you have read my question, where I describe the problem more coherently than is possible in a comment.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you keep insisting on fundamentally misunderstanding how escape sequences work and there is nothing I can do about it. All I can say is that I'd recommend you to remove this question entirely because it is completely misleading and can only confuse other people.

Comment: My question boils down to this: why does wxTextEntryDialog convert '\n' into '\\n'  Is there a better way to workaround this, than the one I have posted?

Comment: Once you understand that `wxTextEntryDialog` doesn't convert anything, you will have the answer to your question. For the very last time, two ASCII characters "backslash" (0x5c) and "n" (0x6e) have absolutely nothing in common with the ASCII "new line" (0xa) represented as `\n` in C sources.